# C++ Embedding QR Code in BMP

Tags: c++, bitmap, qr-code

I have been using LibQREncode to create QR codes based upon a given filename. This is all working fine, and I now need to embed that generated QR code into the corner of a BMP image.

I have researched for a while and found a couple methods of changing a few pixels etc but nothing that really helped me with this. If anyone has an idea of a library or method of inserting the QR image directly into another it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for steganography or to put the image on top of the other (e.g. watermark) ?

Comment: sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library

Comment: it really depends on the framework you have. With SDL you can blit surfaces onto each other and save the result in a bmp. From command line ImageMagick might what you want to use, or if you just have an array of pixels, you can write your own blit function if you really don't wan dependencies. So please more info

Comment: not steganography, will want the normal bmp file with the qr code showing in a corner. Atm I have code that generates an image of the QR code so will be merging the two images rather than using an array of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick that has c++ library, take a look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/).

I use it directly from terminal and, believe me, is powerfull and easy.

From terminal I usually run:

```
convert A.png B.png -geometry +x+y -composite C.png
```

Comment: Thanks! Used graphicsMagick but basically the same thing and same command.